# Brew linkapps deprecated, unable to install on Mac

Tags: solidity, mac-osx

brew linkapps solidity
Warning: brew linkapps has been deprecated and will eventually be removed!

Unfortunately brew linkapps cannot behave nicely with e.g. Spotlight using
either aliases or symlinks and Homebrew formulae do not build "proper" .app
bundles that can be relocated. Instead, please consider using brew cask and
migrate formulae using .apps to casks.

From: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/installing-solidity.html